# Removing logo on headline and add subsections after the Outline slide

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I made a custom latex beamer theme with my University's logo and title on header (top right) and sections (top left). I want to change the the header's settings by including the subsections at the top right section and removing the logo and the university's title. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! If you would tell is how you made your custom theme, we might be able to tell you how to change it. Right now it would require a crystal ball to answer your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e9pyJ77WrxSAHY8PXcAk0zvmmRFUvvev Sorry about my sloppy code.

Comment: Could you include the code of your original headline definition in your questions, so it will be still useful for future users in case the linked file vanished?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new headline definition as following:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{magda theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{tuc_logo_3}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
%      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
%    \end{beamercolorbox}%
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
%      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
%    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
```

and switch between headlines like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tuc}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[tuc theme]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[magda theme]

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This did work but the logo and title are removed from all slides. I would like to keep the initial header format until the Outline slide. I want the subsections to appear only after the Outline slide.

Comment: @MagdaAmiridi please see my edit

Comment: @MagdaAmiridi You're welcome!